# scorep qt error undefined reference to `POMP2_Assign_handle'

Tags: c++, qt, linker

Trying to connect simplest OpenMP QT project with score-P:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QFile>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(200);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i ++)
    {
        QFile file(QString("test_file_%1").arg(i));
        if(file.open(QIODevice::Append))
        {
                QTextStream stream(&file);
                stream << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(Qt::ISODate) + "\n";
                file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Make some changes in *.pro:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS       += -g -fopenmp
QMAKE_LIBS               += -lgomp -lpthread

QMAKE_CXX =  /home/monika/scorep/bin/scorep g++
QMAKE_LINK = /home/monika/scorep/bin/scorep g++
```

And cathing LINK error:

```
/home/monika/scorep/bin/scorep g++ -c -m64 -pipe -g -fopenmp -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-       D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I../test-scorep -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include -I../../scorep/include/opari2 -I. -I../test-scorep -I. -o main.o ../test-scorep/main.cpp
/home/monika/scorep/bin/scorep g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o test-scorep main.o     -lgomp -lQtCore -lpthread  
main.o: In function `POMP2_Init_reg_bl9o0ezmjm8_1':
/home/monika/test/build-test-scorep-Desktop-Release/main.prep.cpp.opari.inc:15:     undefined reference to `POMP2_Assign_handle'
main.o: In function `main.omp_fn.0':
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `pomp_tpd_'
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `POMP2_Parallel_begin'
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `POMP2_For_enter'
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `POMP2_Implicit_barrier_enter'
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `POMP2_Implicit_barrier_exit'
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `POMP2_For_exit'
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `POMP2_Parallel_end'
main.o: In function `main':
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `POMP2_Parallel_fork'
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `pomp_tpd_'
/home/monika/test/test-scorep/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `POMP2_Parallel_join'
```

If i compile simple project (with only one file) like:

```
/home/monika/scorep/bin/scorep g++ main.cpp
```

Everything work (score-P too). If I change QMAKE_CXX or QMAKE_LINK to default (g++) bulding will be well, but score-P will not work.
I tried to include pomp2_lib.h (which contains functions from unfounded list), but still no result (nothing changed).

Comment: Replace `QMAKE_LIBS               += -lgomp -lpthread` with `LIBS += -lgomp -lpthread`. Also, if it is not in a standard library location, use -L/path/to/gomp, too. In fact, I am not sure why you are using all the QMAKE_* prefixes. End user applications should not do that usually.

Comment: Nothing changes. Everything work well if i not using score-P (changes only QMAKE_CXX and QMAKE_LINK)

Comment: Where is your pomp2 library located, and what is the name of it? Have you double checked with `nm -a` or `objdump` if it contains the necessary symbols?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Cmake.  Have you made any progress?